# edit posts using express REST API

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, angularjs, express

I've got an angular-express app with mongoose and mongoDB

for the angular portion I have:

```
.controller('EditPostCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$location', '$routeParams', function($scope, $http, $location, $routeParams){
    // populate the form
    $scope.form = {};
    $http.get('/api/post/' + $routeParams.post_id)
        .success(function(data){
            $scope.form = data;
        });

    // save changes and redirect
    $scope.editPost = function(){
        $http.put('/api/post/' + $routeParams.post_id, $scope.form)
            .success(function(data){
                $location.url('/post/' + $routeParams.post_id);
            });
    };
}])
```

Then for the express portion I have a route:

```
app.put('/api/post/:post_id', posts.editPost);


exports.editPost = function(req, res){
    var updatedPost = {
        title: req.body.title,
        text: req.body.text,
        created: req.body.created
    };

    Post.update({ _id: req.body._id }, updatedPost, function(err, affected){
        console.log('affected %d', affected);
    });
};
```

After I start the server I can update posts but after the edit I don't get redirected to `'/post/' + $routeParams.post_id` like I declare in angular. What do I need in the editPost function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to send and answer to the client, for instance that everything was updated, but no content is returned (204):

```
exports.editPost = function(req, res){
    var updatedPost = {
        title: req.body.title,
        text: req.body.text,
        created: req.body.created
    };

    Post.update({ _id: req.body._id }, updatedPost, function(err, affected){
        console.log('affected %d', affected);

        //returns with no body, but OK:
        //res.send(204);
        //returns with update entity as body:
        res.send(200, updatedPost);
    });
};
```

See also [Express API](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.send).

Comment: okay this works but I've never seen that 204 used in other people's code, is there a better way to edit records given the angular I have?

Comment: Well, one could argue that after an update the server should return the updated entity as body with a 200. I added an example to the code - I hope I understood mongoose correctly :)

Comment: You could also try to use [$resource](http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.1/docs/api/ngResource.$resource) and creating you Express services accordingly